# python3 json sorting by int TypeError

Tags: json, sorting, python-3.6

I am trying to sort this json data by the popularity int field:

```
{
"data": [
{
"albumNum": 0,
"trackNum": 1,
"trackName": "Something You Don't Know About",
"albumName": "The Shifts",
"trackID": "24oeJBDaT3MYURKl2xHaZn",
"popularity": 1
},
{
"albumNum": 0,
"trackNum": 2,
"trackName": "Spring",
"albumName": "The Shifts",
"trackID": "4bOBf4CHUv1Ydac7Pmctcn",
"popularity": 3
},
{
"albumNum": 0,
"trackNum": 3,
"trackName": "Half Life",
"albumName": "The Shifts",
"trackID": "0j9OhCDp2KYrg9VprQ3UPB",
"popularity": 2
}   ]
}
```

I am trying to sort them in order by the popularity int, and am trying to understand it so I could reverse the order from greatest to least greatest value and vice versa, I am trying to do so with the sorted command below:

```
json_data = json.dumps(popularifyData_json)

try:
json_data_sorted = sorted(json_data['data'].items(), key=lambda t: int(t['popularity']))
except Exception as e:
print(type(e))
```

But am getting a class 'TypeError', how can i improve the syntax of my sorted() line usage? thanks.

Comment: changed the print(e) and removed .items(), but am still facing an error now saying 'string indices must be integers'   json_data_sorted = sorted(json_data['data'], key=lambda t: int(t['popularity']))

Comment: Is `json_data` a string or an in-memory, parsed dictionary? If it's a string, call `json_data = json.loads(json_data)` and your code should work, but your example doesn't show it as a string.

Comment: Great. You should write an answer below and mark it as accepted. It might help future visitors who have the same problem.